# Ruby shortcut to "exists && =="

Tags: ruby, refactoring

I have this line of code, which defines `new_params` depending on whether there is an existing user:

```
new_params = params[:existing_user] && params[:existing_user] == "1" ?
  existing_user_params(nested_donation_params) :
  nested_donation_params
```

It's quite long. Is there any method like this to make it a bit shorter and cleaner?

```
e.exists_and_equals("1")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a couple of things to remember here. First is you can compare straight up:

```
params[:existing_user] == "1"
```

If this is `nil == "1"` then it will return `false` anyway. My preferred structure for handling this is:

```
case (params[:existing_user])
when "1"
  existing_user_params(nested_donation_params)
else
  nested_donation_params
end
```

Now depending on what `existing_user_params` does you may have a way of simplifying this even more. For example, if `existing_user_params` is a helper method:

```
def existing_user_params
  case (params[:existing_user])
  when "1"
    fetch_existing_user_params
  else
    { }
  end
end
```

Then you can eliminate the branch:

```
new_params = existing_user_params.merge(nested_donation_params)
```

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know you could compare `nil == "1"` like that. However, what if the variable is not merely nil, but not defined at all?

Comment: Oh, just found out that hashes return `nil` when you search with a non-existing key. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Ruby v2.3.0 introduced [Hash#dig](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Hash.html#method-i-dig). This allows you to replace

```
params[:existing_user] && params[:existing_user]
```

with

```
params.dig(:existing_user)
```

For example,

```
params = { existing_user: "Hank" } 

params.dig(:existing_user)     #=> "Hank"
params.dig(:non_existent_user) #=> "Nil"
```

If we had

```
params = { a: { b: "Dotty" } }
```

we could write

```
params.dig(:a, :b) #=> "Dotty"
params.dig(:c, :b) #=> nil
params.dig(:a, :c) #=> nil
```

v2.3.0 also gave us [Array#dig](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Array.html#method-i-dig).

Comment: That's right! I forgot for hashes the proper method is `.dig`